# Convert SQL to Linqe

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Can someone please help convert the following into LINQ To SQL query?

```
select e.date,e.StudentId, sum(q.Value)[sumation]

from [dbo].[EvaluationResults] e,[dbo].[QuestionsDetails] q

where e.QuestionsDetailsId=q.Id and e.StudentId=9
group by e.StudentId , e.Date
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is happy to help troubleshoot, but should not be used to solve the problem entirely. Can you post what you've got so far, and what problems or errors you are encountering?

Comment: Can please help me to convert the following from LINQ To SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you'll be needing to construct is going to be fairly complex due to the joining and grouping. Since linq can get pretty goofy in those situations, I'll take a stab at it.

This won't perfectly solve the problem for you - you'll need to substitute in your original data context, and may have to rework some bits of the query based on your data types.

```
var results = // This section maps to the FROM part of SQL
              from result in _db.EvaluationResults
              join detail in _db.QuestionDetails
                on result.QuestionDetailsId equals detail.Id
              // This section maps to the WHERE part of SQL
              where result.StudentId == 9
              // Since variable scoping is difficult for grouping,
              // you need to specify an intermediate select object
              // before grouping. It needs to contain everything
              // that is included in grouping or selection.
              select new
              {
                  result.StudentId,
                  result.Date,
                  detail.Value
              } into intermediate
              // This section maps to the GROUP BY part of SQL
              group intermediate by new
              {
                  intermediate.StudentId,
                  intermediate.Date
              } into grouped
              // This section maps to the SELECT part of SQL
              select new
              {
                  grouped.Key.StudentId,
                  grouped.Key.Date,
                  Summation = grouped.Sum(a => a.Value)
              };
```